# how to solve "500 (Internal Server Error)" (Laravel - ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have this problem when trying to bring the data of a route through AJAX.

I want to make a Dynamic Select that according to the "Faculty" chosen, show the "programs" that belong to that faculty.

this is my route

```
Route::get('selectprogramas/{id}', 'SyllabusController@getProgramas');
```

This is the model of Programas

```
    class Programa extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Programas';

    protected $fillable = [ 'nombre', 'perfil_profesional', 'competencias', 'facultad_id', 
    'perfil_profesional'];

    public function selectprogramas($id){
        return Programa::Where('facultad_id', $id)->get();
    }

}
```

this is the function in the controller

```
public function getProgramas(Request $request, $id){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $programas = Programa::selectprogramas($id);
            return response()->json($programas); 
        }
    }
```

these are the two select in the html, I use Laravel Collective

```
<div class="form-group col-9 font-weight-bold">
        {{ Form::label('facultad', 'Facultades:') }}
        {{ Form::select('facultad', $facultades, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'facultad']) }}
</div>

    <div class="form-group col-9 font-weight-bold">
        {{ Form::label('programa', 'Programas:') }}
        {!! Form::select('programa', ['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'], null, ['id'=>'programa']) !!}
    </div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
$("#facultad").change(function (event){
    console.log("entre!!");
    $.get("../selectprogramas/" + event.target.value + "" ,function(response, facultad){
        $("#programa").empty();
        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
            $("#programa").append("<option>"+response[i].nombre+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

the error I have is this:

[image]

Comment: Check the Laravel logs, or set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` to expose details about the error. A 500 error means there's a useful error message somewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

already solved!
I made this change in controller function

```
public function getProgramas(Request $request, $id){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $programas = Programa::where('facultad_id', $id)->get();
        return response()->json($programas); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If that fixed it, the likely issue is that `public function selectprogramas` should've been `public static function selectprogramas` in your original code so it could be called statically. There's probably an error in your logs about calling a non-static function statically.